# Using DNS as a URN resolver

Tags: dns, urn

I'm looking to either find or build a URN ([Universal Resource Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name)) resolver, which would return 0 or more URIs for a given URN.

For example: `urn:fooid:6e8bc430-9c3a-11d9-9669-0800200c9a66:foo` might resolve to `http://www.example.com/fooservice/6e8bc430-9c3a-11d9-9669-0800200c9a66/foo`. The service would be aware of `fooid`-style URNs and know how to look-up the base-URL (http://www.example.com/fooservice/) from the GUID and convert the colons to slashes to make a complete URI.

I've searched for "URN resolvers" but there's not much out there. Then it occurred to me that--since DNS is all about quickly resolving addresses in a scalable and distributed fashion, and since it has been used for other applications ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Other_applications))--maybe it could be used to do the base-URL lookup part.

Has this been done before, and would it be a practical alternative to just using a conventional database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this in DNS you would need to use `NAPTR` records as part of a Dynamic Delegation Discovery System Application, as defined in [RFC 3401](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3401), [RFC 3402](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3402) and [RFC 3403](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3403).

For URN resolution in particular, also see [RFC 3404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3404) and [RFC 3405](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3405) which builds on the previous three to provide a standard way to map URNs to something else.

Ideally if this was a global general-purpose URN you would request a delegation of `fooid` within the `urn.arpa.` domain space.

Take a look at [IANA's website](http://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces/urn-namespaces.xml) to see the existing registered URN namespaces.